# Create a list of numbered linux folders in specific ranges

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

In a specific folder I have got about 10,000 subfolders. All these folders have got numeric names only and I need to create a list of all existing foldernames from 0 to 60,000. The only way I know is using the * wildcard with the find command. Using < or > does not really work for me.

Is there any kind of documentation or hint I may have overseen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use awk to filter out your directory list:

```
ls | awk '{if ($1 < 60000) print $1}'
```

Lots of documentation and tutorials exist for awk.

Answer (score 0):

Who asked you this question, your teacher?

IIUC, correctly, this will do the job in `Bash`:

```
for i in {0..60000}; do test -d "$i" && echo "$i" exists; done
```